# How to decouple the lifetime of a generic parameter of a closure to that of the closure itself?

Tags: generics, rust, closures, lifetime

I am working on a rust project for which I wish to store a Vec of boxed closures with a generic parameter to be reused later.
I want to modify each of these stored closures to add some common processing, but several versions of the code that I expect to be able to use have issues requiring some `'static` bound on the generic parameter of the closures which I think is not actually required, as the lifetime of `T` should be independent of that of the closure.

All the presented examples can be run in the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=333257bb02ee35c1e38ce534996954e1), easily commenting and uncommenting the relevant function to test.
Furthermore, all the examples use the following type alias for clarity:

```rust
pub type MyOp<T> = dyn Fn(&mut String, &mut T);
```

The example below shows the problematic code:

```rust
fn test<T>() -> Vec<Box<MyOp<T>>> {
    let mut operators: Vec<Box<MyOp<T>>> = Vec::default();

    let mut add_op = |operator: Box<MyOp<T>>| {
        let operator_bis = move |s: &mut _, t: &mut _| {
            operator(s, t);
            // Do something else with s
        };
        operators.push(Box::new(operator_bis));
    };

    add_op(Box::new(|s, t| ()));
    add_op(Box::new(|s, t| ()));

    operators
}
```

This code fails to compile with with the following error, which I did not expect, as the lifetime of `T` should not impact that of the final boxed closure.

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:14:24
   |
14 |         operators.push(Box::new(operator_bis));
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                        |
   |                        the parameter type `T` must be valid for the static lifetime...
   |                        ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
   |
6  | fn test<T: 'static>() -> Vec<Box<MyOp<T>>> {
   |          +++++++++
```

Interestingly enough, not calling the operator closure allows it to compile, but obviously the code then does not achieve my initial goal.

```rust
fn test<T>() -> Vec<Box<MyOp<T>>> {
    let mut operators: Vec<Box<MyOp<T>>> = Vec::default();

    let mut add_op = |operator: Box<MyOp<T>>| {
        operators.push(operator);
    };

    add_op(Box::new(|_s, _rng| ()));
    add_op(Box::new(|_s, _rng| ()));

    operators
}
```

The example below shows a working version relying on a helper function to modify the closure.
This version has the advantage to accept both boxed and unboxed closure.

```rust
fn add_operator<T>(
    operator: impl Fn(&mut String, &mut T) + 'static,
    operators: &mut Vec<Box<MyOp<T>>>,
) {
    let op = move |s: &mut _, t: &mut _| {
        operator(s, t);
        // Do something else with s
    };
    operators.push(Box::new(op));
}

fn test<T>() -> Vec<Box<MyOp<T>>> {
    let mut operators = Vec::default();
    add_operator(Box::new(|s: &mut _, t: &mut _| ()), &mut operators);
    add_operator(|s, t| (), &mut operators);
    operators
}
```

However, I would have also expected the version below accepting only boxed closures to compile:

```rust
fn add_operator<T>(
    operator: Box<MyOp<T>>,
    operators: &mut Vec<Box<MyOp<T>>>,
) {
    let op = move |s: &mut _ , t: &mut _| {
        operator(s, t);
        // Do something else with s
    };
    operators.push(Box::new(op));
}

fn test<T>() -> Vec<Box<MyOp<T>>> {
    let mut operators = Vec::default();
    add_operator(Box::new(|s: &mut _, t: &mut _| ()), &mut operators);
    add_operator(Box::new(|s: &mut _, t: &mut _| ()), &mut operators);
    operators
}
```

I think it may be related to [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80675) on the rust repository, as the compiler is not able to detect that the lifetime of `T` is not really relevant.
However, I'm not that confident in my understanding of the lifetime issues related to closures, and before opening an issue I would like to know if someone can pinpoint a mistake in my code or if indeed all the version should be able to compile.

*Added information after edit below.*

---

As both the comments and answer received up to that point explain how to make the example compile, considering the hidden `'static` bound on the `dyn` type alias, I tried to come up with a good example to show that I wanted to have `T` lifetime be independent to that of the function.

The goal is to be able to do things as in the example below, where the function should be able to be called with any `Cow`, but actually fails, even using the version that I originally thought was working.
In this case, the lifetime of `a` even though it should not come into play as it is not used after the call to the operator.

```rust
fn main() {
    let operators_cow = test::<Cow<'_, [u32]>>();

    let mut s = String::new();
    let a = [10u32, 20];
    let mut t = Cow::from(a.as_slice());
    operators_cow[0](&mut s, &mut t);

    drop(operators_cow); // Does not compile if uncommented 
}
```

Comment: `pub type MyOp<T> = dyn Fn(&mut String, &mut T);` is equivalent to `pub type MyOp<T> = dyn Fn(&mut String, &mut T) + 'static`; because there is no lifetime in `MyOp<T>`. See [default trait object lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes)

Comment: @cafce25 Even adding a lifetime as `type MyOp<'a, T> = dyn Fn(&mut String, &mut T) + 'a;`, and even playing around adding other lifetimes, I end up with `T` that must outlive my closure lifetime, even though I think it should be independent (as exemplified in the working helper function case).
Do you have an example of a lifetime combination that make the first version work for any lifetime of `T` ?

Answer (score 0):

As cafce25 points out, `pub type MyOp<T> = dyn Fn(&mut String, &mut T);` is equivalent to `pub type MyOp<T> = dyn Fn(&mut String, &mut T) + 'static;`. You need to add a lifetime to the type alias, and also functions using it.

Your code compiles if you properly annotate it with lifetimes:

```rust
pub type MyOp<'a, T> = dyn Fn(&mut String, &mut T) + 'a;

fn add_operator<'a, T: 'a>(
    operator: Box<MyOp<'a, T>>,
    operators: &mut Vec<Box<MyOp<'a, T>>>,
) {
    let op = move |s: &mut _ , t: &mut _| {
        operator(s, t);
        // Do something else with s
    };
    operators.push(Box::new(op));
}

fn test<'a, T: 'a>() -> Vec<Box<MyOp<'a, T>>> {
    let mut operators = Vec::default();
    add_operator(Box::new(|s: &mut _, t: &mut _| ()), &mut operators);
    add_operator(Box::new(|s: &mut _, t: &mut _| ()), &mut operators);
    operators
}
```

Comment: If this is the problem, why do the working versions work? They should fail with the same error.

Comment: I have edited my question and added a new answer, hopefully clarifying the question, and actually noticing that the versions that work actually only work more than the other ones, but are still actually not decoupling the lifetime of `T` with that of the closure itself.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to clarify my question showed that even the version that I was thinking was working was actually not valid in all the cases I intended.

This led me to find other resources, such as [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/bounding-generic-parameter-to-hrtb/82375) rust lang forum post and [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1481) rust Github issue.

It made me realise that what I actually wanted to express is something akin to one of the following two lines:

```rust
type MyOp<T: Trait> = dyn for<'a,'b> Fn(&'a mut String, &'b mut T) where T: 'b;

type MyOp = dyn for<'a,'b, T where T: Trait + 'b> Fn(&'a mut String, &'b mut T);
```

This is obviously incorrect Rust, but the idea is that I want I want to have `T` lifetime be something similar to the explicit lifetimes in `type MyOp<T> = dyn for<'a,'b> Fn(&'a mut String, &'b mut T)`, where we should accept the infinity of `T` that satisfy the bounds.
This means that `T` lifetime should not decided when generating the `Vec` of operators, but when the operator is called.

It looks like we are then going into higher kinded types territory, which I am not familiar with.
Besides, these are not available in Rust anyway, at least on the stable branch.

Therefore, I think that the answer to my problem is that it is not currently feasible without some complex helper traits/macro shenanigans that would make the code really hard to understand.

If anyone has a better answer than this one to my (hopefully) clarified issue, I would be happy to be proved wrong with a simple solution.

Comment: There cannot be, ever, dynamically-dispatched higher-ranked types, since the code needs to be monomorphized. However, depending on what you need from `T`, you may be able to go with `&mut dyn SomeTrait`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oh, that's right ! 

But then, from what I understand, lifetimes should not affect monomorphization (correct me if I am wrong). Therefore, is there a way to modify my code so that in the example using `Cow` in my edited question can be made to compile while dropping `a` before `operators` ? Here, `T` is fixed, and therefore should not require dynamic higher ranked types, right ? 

Here is a simplified [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec2d657aa2ca05c388c52a9588e009cb) with this example.